# Angular equivalent of index() from jquery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use Angular 1.5. I have two selects and I need to update 2nd select depending on the index of the option of 1st select.

Is there an easy way to get the index of option selected? Like from `0` to `5`.

My 1st select is :

```
<select class="form-control" name="idEtablissement" ng-model="infosEtab.idEtablissement" ng-change="updateContrats()"
    ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in listeEtablissement'>
</select>
```

I need something like that :

```
// return -1, listeEtablissement is [{id: 2, name: 'Test'}, {...}]
alert($scope.listeEtablissement.indexOf($scope.infosEtab.id));
```

$listeEtablissement is :

```
[{id: 2, name: 'Test'}, {id: 5, name: 'Test 2'}]
```

But I need to have the index, like 0 or 1.

**EDITED**

Ok I'll use Javascript approach, the most simple one :

```
$scope.updateContrats = function() {
    var index = document.getElementById('idEtablissement').selectedIndex;
    // ....
}
```

Comment: what is this returning `$scope.infosEtab.idEtablissement`

Comment: What does `$scope.listeEtablissement` contains show us the sample data so that we can suggest what you can do

Comment: Edited, listeEtablissement is an array of objects without index.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I just need the index of 1st selected. Javascript version works. I'll close my question soon.

Comment: I have answered my question as I said, Javascript version is working fine. Your answer can work too I think. I'll accept.

Comment: Glad to help ya!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it by native JavaScript using `array.findIndex();` like in this [runnable demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25vp3sd6/).

- [MDN reference of array.findindex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select class="form-control" 
          name="idEtablissement" 
          ng-model="infosEtab.idEtablissement" 
          ng-change="updateContrats()" 
          ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in listeEtablissement'>
  </select>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectedIndex = null;
  $scope.listeEtablissement = [{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Test'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Test 2'
  }];

  $scope.updateContrats = function() {
    $scope.selectedIndex = $scope.listeEtablissement.findIndex(function(item) {
      return item.id === $scope.infosEtab.idEtablissement
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

ng-options

to

```
index as item.name for (index, item) in listeEtablissement
```

Comment: But I need ID as value for my model.

Comment: You can get the ID. using listeEtablissement[infosEtab.idEtablissement].id in your updateContrats function

Comment: If you want to set a model variable for binding to some other place in you view. you could create a new scope variable and assign to it the ID inside updateContracts function